# Stored procedure select max value and insert

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am trying to select max: value from a table and insert value into same table.

The code is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertLogin]
    @LOG_ID INT OUTPUT,
    @LOG_NAME VARCHAR(100),
    @LOG_EMAIL VARCHAR(100)
AS
    INSERT INTO login(LOG_NAME, LOG_EMAIL) 
    VALUES(@LOG_NAME, @LOG_EMAIL)

    SET @LOG_ID = @@IDENTITY
```

The other values are inserting except LOG_ID its getting null.

Comment: what column in table `login` that has a property of `IDENTITY`?

Comment: I think that was the issue how can I set that.?

Comment: ok, what column do you want to set as auto incrementing value? do you have an `ID` the unique identifies the row?

Comment: ok here,http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/03/sql-server-add-or-remove-identity-property-on-column/

Comment: It's fine now thanks a lot. :-)

Answer (score 1):

My guess is your Log_Id column in your Login table is not setup to be an Identity.

Through T-SQL, you have to drop and readd the column:

```
alter table login
drop column log_id

alter table login
alter column log_id int not null Identity(1,1)
```

Alternatively you can do this pretty easily in SSMS.  Here's a decent article on the subject:

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/03/sql-server-add-or-remove-identity-property-on-column/

I'd also recommend using `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` over `@@Identity`